# Image behind text on hover CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get an image to show up behind the text as a hover effect.

It is just a simple splash page for now, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

Here is the current page. The words below the logo are links. 
https://gyazo.com/8fac5b310ed8febd80032cc19b57d76e

Here is the image I want behind the text when a user hovers.
https://gyazo.com/67852dd57789458942952b1dd3b3cb55

It is like a scribble effect in different colors. They wouldn't all show up at one, but just the different one behind each word as you hover.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lira.net</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="middlegroup">
<div id="topimage">
<img src="images/LiraLogo325.png">
</div>
<div id="links">
     <p>
        <a href="#">Liquidation</a> -
        <a href="#">Monetization<a> -
        <a href="#">Brokerage</a>
     </p>

</div>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
<p>&copy; 2016 Lira.net </p>
</footer>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
h1 {
font-family: "Open Sans" , serif; 
color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #4d4d4d;
font-size: 5vw;
text-align: center;
}

body {
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#topimage{
width: 100%;

text-align:center;
size: 1vw;
}
#links{
width: 100%;
list-style-type:circle;
}
#middlegroup{
width:600px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-125px 0 0 -300px;
}
a:link{
color:#01197d;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
color:#01197d;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration: none;

}
a:active{
color:#01197d;
text-decoration: none;
}
p {
font-family: "Open Sans" , serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size:15px;
text-align:center;
}
ul {
font-family: "Open Sans" , serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
list-style-type:circle;
}
footer p{
font-family: "Open Sans" , serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size:14px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to use the same background image and have it positioned differently, read up on CSS Sprites.

Comment: if the `p` is a set height and width, you can do `p:hover { background-image:url('..image.jpg');`  Or you can do this for each `a` on hover

Comment: @ntgCleaner If I were to do it for each a `a` how would I go about that?

Comment: in your `a:hover {...}`  Just add a `background-image:url('../image,jpg');` and make sure each has the different color in it.  You can use `background-position` if you want to use one sprite for all of them

Comment: @ntgCleaner I guess I'm still not following. I put in the `background-image` with link in my `a:hover` but nothing is showing up on the hover. Hmmm.

Comment: @JacobDoty, Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rd7zbytc/

Comment: @ntgCleaner you nailed it man! I appreciate it so much!

Comment: No problem!  I'll toss the fiddle and stuff in an answer for future reference of searchers

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this done is to use background images
You can try something like this:

```
.class1:hover {
background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
.class2:hover {
background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
.class3:hover {
background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

Just replace the class names for the ones that suits your links, and obviously play with sizing, something like display inline-block to the links will be enough. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) you have everything you will need for this task

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to add a background image on hover.  Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rd7zbytc/

and here's the code:

```
#links p a:hover {
    background-image:url("https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
    background-size:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are talking about?

http://codepen.io/xkurohatox/pen/qbPXOb

HTML changes:

```
 <div id="links">
 <p>
    <a id="a1" href="#">Liquidation</a> -
    <a id="a2" href="#">Monetization<a> -
    <a id="a3" href="#">Brokerage</a>
    </p>

 </div>
```

CSS changes:

```
#a1:hover {
background-image:url("http://previews.123rf.com/images/pzaxe/pzaxe1104/pzaxe110400016/9242659-Seamless-monochrome-square-texture-scribble--Stock-Vector-pattern- scribble-background.jpg");
 background-size:100%;
}
#a2:hover {
background-image:url("http://st.depositphotos.com/1466799/1121/v/950/dep_11211843-Full-color-abstract-scribble-background.jpg");
 background-size:100%;
}
 #a3:hover {
  background-image:url("http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/child-scribble-12020973.jpg");
 background-size:100%;
}
/* images above are not my own and only being used for demo purposes */
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes this helped out, but how can I get the image to be outside of just the rectangle of text. To where the image is actually bigger than the height and width of the text. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check the link again. I edited it for you by adding:  padding:10px 0px; <-- this adds padding to the top and bottom of the image (aka makes top and bottom larger but keeps sides the same. Otherwise the links are pushed to the side when you hover.

Comment: PS: If you want the image on the left and right too you can use this: http://codepen.io/xkurohatox/pen/zrEdNx I added #a1, #a2, #a3 {
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
} which adds padding around top, bottom, left, and right of the text before hover. Then changed padding:10px 0px; to  padding:10px; so the image surrounds entire text. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: yes this helped a ton! It's just duplicating the image on the bottom, when I'd like the anchor point to be dead center on the text and go out from that point. You're a life saver. Thanks!